# Play an opus file with gstreamer and pulseaudio

Tags: gstreamer, pulseaudio, opus

I cannot figure out an `gst-launch` invocation to simply play an opus file to pulseaudio. Any help?

Things I've tried

```
130 % file foo.opus
foo.opus: Ogg data, Opus audio, version 0.1, stereo, 44100 Hz (Input Sample Rate)

0 % gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=foo.opus ! pulsesink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstPulseSink:pulsesink0: The stream is in the wrong format.

1 % gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=foo.opus ! opusparse ! pulsesink
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link opusparse0 to pulsesink0

1 % gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=foo.opus ! opusdec ! pulsesink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0: Internal data stream error.

# this runs, but only makes one burst of noise
0 % gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=foo.opus ! opusparse ! opusdec ! pulsesink
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=foo.opus ! oggdemux ! opusparse ! opusdec ! alsasink
```

I was able to piece this together from the example pipelines here

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/opus/opusdec.html?gi-language=c

and

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/opus/opusenc.html?gi-language=c

Although, in those examples, there is no `opusparse`. I don't know why `opusparse` is needed for my files, but it isn't needed for `sine.ogg` created with opusenc. Or what the difference is between parsing and decoding the opus file data ...